# Is there a way to specify a type must fail deserialization unless a custom converter is used?

Tags: c#, json.net

Let's say I have a class, `Foo`, which has a custom converter,

```
public class FooConverter : JsonConverter { ...
```

The reason that `FooConverter` exists is that a `Foo` created by the normal deserializer will result in an incorrectly initialised instance. So `FooConverter` must always be used to serialize/deserialize instances of `Foo`.

Currently, I achieve this by having a private constructor in Foo, which has a parameter:

```
class Foo
{
    private Foo(int _) {}

    public Foo(string x, string y) : this(0)
    {
        ...
```

Any attempt to have Json.NET work with `Foo` now will result in a `JsonSerializationException`. unless `FooConverter` is registered and used.

But this seems really messy. I assume there must be a way of marking the class, eg with an attribute, to tell Json.NET to not deserialize it? [All I can find is the `ConstructorHandling` enum](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ConstructorHandling.htm), but that doesn't have a "do not use a non-public constructor" option.

Am I missing something, or do I have to continue using my "hack" approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So `FooConverter` must always be used to serialize/deserialize instances of `Foo`.

Then annotate the class:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
public class Foo
{
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Not sure how I missed that, but that's exactly what I needed! Thanks.